# "Banning" programs from Windows 7's Recently Launched list

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have a laptop I use for home and work. I like to keep them separate as best I can, and it's not very endearing to my clients to sit down in a meeting with them, crack open my start menu, and have WoW at the top of the list. Is there a way to "ban" a program from this list so that--no matter how much I use it--it will never pop in there again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a toolbar (Yes, they still work in windows 7!) to launch programs like that.  Because the toolbar has more icons on it than fit in the space I've allowed on the task bar, there's a little >> symbol (except the symbol goes down) that acts like a second menu.  Programs shown the toolbar do not migrate to the start menu's most recently used programs list.

Here's the toolbar on my taskbar. The four most used icons are shown.  I have about 20 others that show up with a name when I click on the >>. My taskbar is vertical on the right side.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> I like to keep them separate as best I
>   can

use two separate accounts.

Comment: This is a very good idea, I'll consider it--I think Knox has what I wanted, though.

Comment: Yes, his solution is better for this *exact* problem. Having two separate accounts, however, will solve *any* possible similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility that I have not tried myself is to edit the registry as in [This post at Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/21866-exclude-programs-start-menu-list.html#post235515/)

Answer (score 0):

If you pin it to the taskbar, it'll only have a little icon, instead of icon AND text